# I am trying to throw an exception from another function, but it crashes and gives me unhandled exception. What should I do instead? c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

`//checks every turn whether player 1 or player 2 wins using switch and case method
void caseCheck()
{
    //when a player wins
    if (x == "O" && y == "O" && z == "O" || a == "O" && b == "O" && c == "O" || d == "O" && e == "O" && f == "O" || x == "O" && a == "O" && d == "O" || y == "O" && b == "O" && e == "O" || z == "O" && c == "O" && f == "O" || x == "O" && b == "O" && f == "O" || z == "O" && b == "O" && d == "O")
    {
        system("cls");
        mainBoard();
        cout << endl << "player 2 wins";
        throw; // here is where the error is
    }
    if (x == "X" && y == "X" && z == "X" || a == "X" && b == "X" && c == "X" || d == "X" && e == "X" && f == "X" || x == "X" && a == "X" && d == "X" || y == "X" && b == "X" && e == "X" || z == "X" && c == "X" && f == "X" || x == "X" && b == "X" && f == "X" || z == "X" && b == "X" && d == "X")
    {
        system("cls");
        mainBoard();
        cout << endl << "player 1 wins";
        throw; // here is where the error is
    }
}

//prints X to current players desired spot with user input
void exes()
{
    caseCheck();
    mainBoard();
    cout << endl << "Player 1: pick a number of where you would like to go ";
    cin >> currentMove;
    system("cls");
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        mainBoard();
        cout << endl << "cannot enter letter values" << endl;
        exes();
    }
    switch (currentMove)
    {
        case 1:
            //run check function for already inputted values
            x = "X";
            movesMade[0] = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            y = "X";
            movesMade[1] = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            z = "X";
            break;
        case 4:
            a = "X";
            break;
        case 5:
            b = "X";
            break;
        case 6:
            c = "X";
            break;
        case 7:
            d = "X";
            break;
        case 8:
            e = "X";
            break;
        case 9:
            f = "X";
            break;
        default:
            mainBoard();
            cout << endl << "number is not located on tic tac toe board, try again" << endl;
            exes();
            break;
    }
}

//prints O to current players desired spot with user input
void oes()
{
    caseCheck();
    mainBoard();
    cout << endl << "Player 2: pick a number of where you would like to go ";
    cin >> currentMove;
    system("cls");
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        mainBoard();
        cout << endl << "cannot enter letter values" << endl;
        oes();
    }
    switch (currentMove)
    {
        case 1:
            x = "O";
            break;
        case 2:
            y = "O";
            break;
        case 3:
            z = "O";
            break;
        case 4:
            a = "O";
            break;
        case 5:
            b = "O";
            break;
        case 6:
            c = "O";
            break;
        case 7:
            d = "O";
            break;
        case 8:
            e = "O";
            break;
        case 9:
            f = "O";
            break;
        default:
            mainBoard();
            cout << endl << "number is not located on tic tac toe board, try again" << endl;
            oes();
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            cout << player;
            exes();
            oes();
        }
        exes();
        mainBoard();
        cout << "Tie game";
        throw(player);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}`


in the function caseCheck, I am trying to throw an exception into the main function so I can stop the program. I tried putting exit there or return there, but it didn't do anything and the function continued running. The program does stop like it's supposed to, but it crashes right after giving me an unhandled exception error. What should I do? How should I approach this differently?

Comment: The code doesn't throw an exception. It attempts to rethrow a prior exception, and since there is no prior exception, it quits.

Comment: Don't use an exception here. Exceptions are for unexpected conditions. One player winning the game is certainly not unexpected. Just return a value from the function; callers should check that value when the function returns.

Comment: Ending the game isn't really an exception, it is expected behavior so probably you're better of returning a bool from caseCheck that returns false if the game has ended.
Anyway you should have typed something : throw end_of_game_exception(), with end_of_game_exception inherited from std::exception (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)

Comment: How should I stop the main function from running once the win condition is met? I can't return anything in the casecheck function, and putting exit; doesn't do anything to the main function because it exits the casecheck function. The throw exception was a last-ditch effort just to see if it would work.

Comment: @Pvt. Pancakes If you want casecheck() to return something, please use BOOL caseCheck() and replace "throw" to return true/false;
Also you can use the code below:
if(caseCheck())
{
     exit(0);
}

Comment: Hello, @Pvt.Pancakes, welcome to SO. When asking a question, try to isolate the code that's causing the problem to make it easier to help you. Questions that are mainly code are usually a bad idea.